# Undefined reference errors when linking GLFW on MinGW

Tags: opengl, mingw, glfw

I am trying to develop an openGL application with GLEW and GLFW on Windows using minGW. In the current directory, `project/`, I have the directories `src/`, `bin/`, and `glfw-3.0.4.bin.WIN64/`. I have the files `test.cpp`, `glew.h`, `glew.c`, and `wglew.h` in the `src/` directory.

The directory `./glfw-3.0.4.bin.WIN64/include/` contains the `GLFW/glfw3.h` header file.

The directory `./glfw-3.0.4.bin.WIN64/lib-mingw/` contains `glfw3.dll`, `glfw3dll.a`, and `libglfw3.a`.

My main file, `test.cpp` contains,

```
#include "glew.h"
#include "GLFW/glfw3.h"

#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    printf("Hello, World!\n");

    glewInit();
    glfwInit();
}
```

I am compiling the program from the `project/` directory by running (split into two lines for readability)

```
gcc -DGLEW_STATIC -DGLFW_DLL -o ./bin/test ./src/*.cpp ./src/glew.c 
-I ./glfw-3.0.4.bin.WIN64/include/ -L ./glfw-3.0.4.bin.WIN64/lib-mingw/ -lglfw3 -lopengl32
```

and I am getting the following error:

```
undefined reference to `_imp_glfwInit'
```

I think the problem has to do with me linking the GLFW library incorrectly. From what I understand, including the compiler option `-lglfw3` will tell gcc to link `./glfw-3.0.4.bin.WIN64/lib-mingw/glfw3.dll`, which contains the definition for `glfwInit()`.

I've looked at solutions to other problems similar to mine and they suggest things such as copying the dll file to the source/binary directories and changing the order of the -l options, but none have seemed to solve the problem for me.

Comment: Your gcc command split into two lines. Is it for sake if readability here? Or that is your actual command (in that case, it is wrong)? Also, as I recall, `-Ipath` and `-Lpath` must be written without space.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I should have noted that the gcc command was split for readability. Running the command without spaces still produces the same error.

Comment: Can't say for sure, but I guess something is wrong with your libraries. Are you sure they're mingw-compatible and supposed to be 64bit? Can you get it running with 32bit version?

Comment: Ah, I really thought that would have fixed the problem. I've been using mingw for 32bit systems. I switched to using glfw-3.0.4.bin.WIN32 but I still get the same compile time error.

Comment: Could you assemble minimal example (with all required sources and libraries) and upload it somewhere? It is hard to diagnose this kind of problems without seeing it.

Comment: Sure. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzaMTyFoNpy3RHlCalRpM054bVE/edit?usp=sharing 
It's a bit different from what I have above.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem is that gcc follows strict library naming conventions. It attempts to find `glfw3.dll.a`, but finds none (because it is named `glfw3dll.a` - simple rename will fix your problem).

Next step it looks for `libglfw3.a`, and succeeds - but it is a static library, while reference declared as dynamic in header files (tricky windows DECLSPECs... this problem don't exist on e.g. linux). So, it cannot find `_imp__glfwInit`, because in static library it is called just `glfwInit`, so you getting an error.

Removing `libglfw3.a` is also one of options - in that case gcc will look further and eventually find `glfw3.dll` and use it.

Comment: So many people in the Internet suggest to remove mingw 32 bit version and install Mingw-w64, but it doesn't resolve the issue. I renamed glfw3dll.a to glfw3.dll.a and program launched flawlessly! Second suggestion to remove libglfw3.a and glfw3.dll.a also worked out! You're the master. Can you explain why and how gcc looks for the necessary dll's further, once .a file is not found? So the truth is that actually one of the glfw creators named incorrectly .a files in pre-compiled binaries?

Comment: @JacobTheKnitter I don't think there is any other step, with default settings it tries to link with dynamic library first (`.dll.a` on windows), and if it can't - then it tries static one (`.a`). Direct linking with `.dll` is specific addition gcc toolchain have; for all I know MSVC toolchain can't link with dll directly without use of import libraries (what gcc have in `.dll.a`), so I suppose it just considered as last resort as it could be problemmatic in some cases. I don't think glfw does anything wrong either, they just follow their MSVC naming scheme. You can link with `-lglfw3dll`.

Comment: @JacobTheKnitter declspec is big deal on windows. If your include file says functions are dllimport - they have to be in dll, and attempt to link with static library will produce an error. So if *your* program intends to use glfw in dll form, it have to define `GLFW_DLL` before including `glfw3.h` (note `-DGLFW_DLL` flag in original question), *and* link wtih dll; but as you have to know that at build time, it is probably better to have separate library name for dll version and just link with `-lglfw3dll` to ensure it wouldn't pick static version. You don't have either problem on linux/osx.