# What am I doing wrong with G++ and GLFW?

Tags: c++, g++, glfw, glew

I have the most up-to-date drivers fro my graphics card. I am using glfw 3.2.1 for Windows (glfw-3.2.1.bin.WIN64), the pre-compiled library. I am also using glew 2.1.0 (glew-2.1.0), because I thought maybe I needed that too. I have written a little Powershell script to do all the compiling work for me called "compile TEST.ps1".

I believe I am linking it correctly, but I probably have messed it up anyhow. I have put both the glew32.dll and glfw3.dll inside of my folder with my .cpp file called "main.cpp". Those dlls were also copy-pasted into my System32 file. Whenever I run my script to try and compile the program, it fails with the given error:

```
g++ : C:\Users\USERNAMEHERE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccYYPyBE.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x11): undefined reference to `_imp__glfwInit'
At E:\c++\projected\compile TEST.ps1:1 char:1
+ g++ main.cpp -I"E:\c++\projected\glfw-3.2.1.bin.WIN64\include" -I"E:\ ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (C:\Users\USERNAMEHERE..._imp__glfwInit':String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
```

TLDR:
I am using glfw and glew and trying to compile with g++ and I keep getting this error, and similar like it with all the methods from glfw3.

What have I messed up on? LWJGL was so much nicer.

"compile TEST.ps1"

```
g++ main.cpp -I"E:\c++\projected\glfw-3.2.1.bin.WIN64\include" -I"E:\c++\projected\glew-2.1.0\include" -L"E:\c++\projected\glfw-3.2.1.bin.WIN64\lib-mingw-w64" -L"E:\c++\projected\glew-2.1.0\lib\Release\Win32" -lglfw3 -lglew32 -lopengl32 -lglu32 -lgdi32 -mwindows
./colorCorrection.exe
Pause
```

"colorCorrection.exe" is a program I wrote to fix the discoloration of my powershell instance when g++ did it's thing.

"main.cpp"

```
#define GLEW_STATIC
#include <GL/glew.h>
#define GLFW_DLL
#define GLFW_INCLUDE_GLU
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

int main(){

    glewInit();

    if (!glfwInit()){
        // Initialization failed
    }else{
        glfwTerminate();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is not my first time trying to get this to work, but I always get stuck here.

[image: My folder for my program]

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22623087/undefined-reference-errors-when-linking-glfw-with-mingw-gcc ?

Comment: Sorry, I have actually already followed the possible duplicates instructions posted by Quimby (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22623087/undefined-reference-errors-when-linking-glfw-with-mingw-gcc). That fixed an earlier error I had a long time ago. It does not however, fix this particular error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Undefined reference errors when linking GLFW on MinGW](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22623087/608639)

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Windows programming, but I can't imagine putting custom dlls in `System32/` is good practice. IIRC, a dll will be found if it's in the same directory as the executable being run, which is a much neater solution.