# Undefined references when linking against GLFW?

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw, undefined-reference, glew

**Important:** I didn't use Visual Code (much info in Internet about OpenGL setting up is related to this IDE) (I use VSCode).
As I got, there is OpenGL realization (GLFW) and OpenGL loader, that load OpenGL on specific platform (GLEW):

```cpp
#define GLEW_STATIC
#include <GL/glew.h>
#define GLFW_DLL
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

int main()
{
    glfwInit();
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_FALSE);
    return 0;
}
```

I completely stuck on error:

```
g++ src/main.cpp -lglfw3dll -I.\include\ -L.\lib\ -g -std=c++17 -lopengl32 -lgdi32
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\ccQkrCsr.o: in function 'main':
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\User\Code\OpenGL/src/main.cpp:13: undefined reference to '_imp__glfwWindowHint'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\User\Code\OpenGL/src/main.cpp:15: undefined reference to '_imp__glfwWindowHint'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\User\Code\OpenGL/src/main.cpp:17: undefined reference to '_imp__glfwWindowHint'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\User\Code\OpenGL/src/main.cpp:19: undefined reference to '_imp__glfwWindowHint'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

My project structure:

```
│   glfw3.dll
│
├───include
│   ├───GL
│   │       eglew.h
│   │       glew.h
│   │       glxew.h
│   │       wglew.h
│   │
│   └───GLFW
│           glfw3.h
│           glfw3native.h
│
├───lib
│       glew32s.lib
│       libglfw3dll.a
│
└───src
        main.cpp
```

[Here is the similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22623087/undefined-reference-errors-when-linking-glfw-on-mingw), but it didn't help me.

Comment: @BDL, I tried this and got error:
```
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lglfw3

collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: does the import library exist in ./lib/ ?

Comment: @Raildex, what is the import library? Did you mean "libglfw3.a"?

Comment: You need to link with libglfw3.a or libglfw3dll.a. Probably the dll one since __imp_ means a DLL import